# XML Serializer to object

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I would like to serialize a simple XML file to object:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

-<Tables>


-<StaticGroups>


-<StaticGroup Name="111">


-<Table>

<TableName>Table1 Name</TableName>

<TableTag>Table1 Tag</TableTag>

</Table>


-<Table>

<TableName>Table2 Name</TableName>

<TableTag>Table2 Tag</TableTag>

</Table>

</StaticGroup>


-<StaticGroup>


-<Table>

<TableName>Table3 Name</TableName>

<TableTag>Table3 Tag</TableTag>

</Table>

</StaticGroup>

</StaticGroups>

</Tables>
```

Below are classes:

```
 [XmlRoot("Tables")]
    public class TablesXML
    {
        public TablesXML()
        {
            StaticTablesGroups = new List<StaticTablesGroup>();
        }


        [XmlArray("StaticGroups")]
        [XmlArrayItem("StaticGroup", typeof(StaticTablesGroup))]
        public List<StaticTablesGroup> StaticTablesGroups { get; set; }

    }

    public class StaticTablesGroup
    {
        public StaticTablesGroup()
        {
            GroupTables = new List<GroupTable>();
        }

        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("StaticGroup")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Table", typeof(GroupTable))]
        public List<GroupTable> GroupTables { get; set; }
    }


    public class GroupTable
    {

        [XmlElement("TableName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TableTag")]
        public string Tag { get; set; }
    }
```

List of StaticGroup is properly created with Name attribute.

The problem is that Table/s (TableName and TableTag) are not serialized for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**Edit #1**
Thank you Marc helped with issue #1

Now I'm trying to add StaticGroup inside another StaicGroup

```
-<Tables>


 -<StaticGroups>


-<StaticGroup Name="111">


-<Table>

<TableName>Table1 Name</TableName>

<TableTag>Table1 Tag</TableTag>

</Table>
-<StaticGroup Name="111.1">


-<Table>

<TableName>Table1.1 Name</TableName>

<TableTag>Table1.1 Tag</TableTag>

</Table>
</StaticGroup>
</StaticGroup>
```

Deserialize works right except nested  doesn't get data from XML

modified StaticTablesGroup class:

```
public class StaticTablesGroup
    {
        public StaticTablesGroup()
        {
            GroupTables = new List<GroupTable>();
            StaticTablesGroups = new List<StaticTablesGroup>();
        }

        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        //[XmlArray("StaticGroup")]
        [XmlElement("Table", typeof(GroupTable))]
        public List<GroupTable> GroupTables { get; set; }



        [XmlElement("StaticGroup", typeof(StaticTablesGroup))]
        public List<StaticTablesGroup> StaticTablesGroups { get; set; }        
    }
```

However, I checked Serialize,as Marc suggested, and it worksfine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already *inside* `<StaticGroup>`, so you don't need `[XmlArray("StaticGroup")]`. Instead, use `XmlElement` on the list, which makes it process each instance of `<Table>` as an item in the list, without a wrapping element for the list itself:

```
[XmlElement("Table")]
public List<GroupTable> GroupTables { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. i would like to change the XML to include StaticGroup inside StaticGroup  I modified StaticTableGroup class public class StaticTablesGroup
    {
        ...
       

        [XmlArray("StaticGroup")]
        [XmlArrayItem("StaticGroup", typeof(StaticTablesGroup))]
        public List<StaticTablesGroup> SubGroup { get; set; }
    } But, sub-groups are not deserialized. What am I doing wrong this time

Comment: @Vadim pro tip: use `Serialize` and look at what it generates; compare that to what you wanted - that should tell you where to look. Hard for me to comment without a full example

Comment: Thank you for the tip. When Serialize the XML looks exactly as expected, but reading back doesn't work.